# using the same make file in a separate directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile in directory `foo` and would like to use the same makefile in a subdirectory `bar`. I have been doing the following:

```
all:
   <do work in foo>
   cd bar; 
   make -f ../Makefile <target to make in bar>
```

This gets very messy when I try to do target specific variable values as I need to pass them on the command line when calling `make` in `bar`. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: ```make -C bar``` is equivalent ( in result ) as ```cd bar && make```

Comment: That rule (which can't actually work as written, but never mind) is for calling Make in `foo` and having it reinvoke itself in `bar`. Do you want to call Make in `foo` or in `bar`?

Comment: If the issue is transmission of variables through to the sub-make then perhaps using `$(MAKE)` would be of some use here? That being said I don't actually understand what is desired here or what the current makefile is actually doing (though it looks like it is doing it badly).

Comment: @Carl yes indeed this question needs more attention... from the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell from the question whether the following solution suites your needs, it might - or might not - work for you.

If your situation is that you simply want the same `Makefile` features available, `include` could be a solution. You can create a `Makefile` in directory `bar` in which you do everything you need specific to `bar`, and besides that, you do:

```
include ../foo/Makefile
```

**Caveat!** This doesn't work straight-forward. There cannot be two recipes with the same name. For example, if you want `foo/Makefile` to do `recipeBar` for `all`, and you want `foo/Makefile` to do `recipeFoo` and `recipeBar` for `all`, **the following does not work**:

foo/Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    recipeFoo
```

bar/Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    reciveBar

include foo/Makefile
```

Instead, the recipes have to be separated into unique names. However, dependency rules can be there multiple times, so it's not really a challenge to workaround this caveat. So, the following would work:

foo/Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all: allFoo

.PHONY: allFoo
allFoo:
    recipeFoo
```

bar/Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all: allBar

.PHONY: allBar
allBar:
    recipeBar

include foo/Makefile
```

Now, if you run `make` in `bar`, it would run `recipeFoo` and `recipeBar`.
If the sequence matters to you and `recipeFoo` must run before `recipeBar`, make `allBar` dependent on `allFoo`, like this:

bar/Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all
all: allBar

.PHONY: allBar
allBar: allFoo
    recipeBar

include foo/Makefile
```

If you want your target-specific variables available when you call another `make` (for which I recommend to use `$(MAKE)` not `make`), you can export your variables - with the corresponding consequences (environment space overflow risk on some Windows versions, .

For example, if you have a target-specific variable `FOO` for target `all` in `Makefile`, and you want that when calling `Submake.mak` that variable is known, it works like this:

Makefile:

```
all: export FOO:=bar
.PHONY: all
all:
    $(MAKE) -f Submake.mak
```

Submake.mak:

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    echo $(FOO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a link (hard or symbolic, your choice) in `bar` to `../Makefile`. Then, as Carl points out in his comment, you can `make -C bar` and everything should work. (As of gmake 3.81, at least, make switches to the new directory first, then does its thing. I cannot speak for gmake 4.0.)